# Cannot run any mongod instance anymore due some weird .lock error

Tags: windows, mongodb

I want to start a mongod instance after I didn't use mongodb for a long time.
I'm running it on windowns and executed the following command followed by the error message:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongod --dbpath test2
2016-11-12T14:07:09.299+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: test2\mongod.lock errno:5 Zugriff verweigert. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2016-11-12T14:07:09.299+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

I freshly created the `test2` directory. I found solutions only for linux using `ps` etc.
Please tell me how to get an instance running again.

Answer (score 0):

the previous running instance probably crashed and left the lock file in place. remove the lock file (from your error msg as 'test2\mongod.lock') and restart mongo. you might see mongo have to spend some time cleaning up from the previous crash, though. be patient.

Comment: The problem here is the "file2" folder was freshly created. I removed all .locks before...there's something going wrong it seems.